# Ideal quotient of fractional ideals

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Wat exactly does the notation $$A : (BC)$$ mean? We are talking about fractional R ideals.
From definitions i get,
if $$a \in A:(BC)$$ then $$a(BC)\subset A$$

But what am i saying exactly?

I hope someone can explain this to me.

Comment: Usually the notation $(I:J)$ in commutative algebra refers to an ideal quotient, which is slightly different from a fractional ideal. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_quotient

Answer (score 1):

The usual framework is: $\,R\,$ is an integer domain, $\,K\,$ is its fractions fields, $\,A,B,C\,$ are fractional ideals, i.e.: $\,A\,$ is a fractional ideal if it is a $\,K-\,$ module for which there exists $\,0\neq r\in R\,$ s.t. $\,rA\subset R\,$ .

So by $\,A:BC\,$ you most probably meaning the set of all elements  $\,t\in K\,$ s.t. $\,t(BC)\subset A\,$ .

Comment: A fractional ideal $A$ is an $R$-submodule of $K$ for which there exists a non-zero $r \in R$ such that $rA \subset R$.

Comment: Indeed so, thanks. +1

Answer (score 0):

The following is borrowed from Atiyah-Macdonald:

If $N,P$ are submodules of $M$, we define $(N:P)$ to be the set of all $a\in A$ such that $aP\subset N$. It is an ideal of $A$. In particular, $(0:M)$ is the set of all $a\in A$ such that $aM=0$.